strip_path and preserve_host attributes in KongIngress object
In a k8s cluster we have an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC web application. If I configure an ingress controller using NGINX ingress class -> using request host and path prefix / , target service the cluster IP port 443 all work fine.
If I want to use Kong ingress class -> prefix /onename, target service the cluster IP port 443, strip path true and preserve host to false. I get
{
    "message": "An invalid response was received from the upstream server"
}

The ASP.NET Core MVC web application has the base path /.
How can I configure the ingress controller with Kong ingress class?
I want to navigate for example:
https://res0ingresskong.resources.root.gc.local/onename
routing to / of my ASP.NET Core MVC app on the cluster


I want to navigate for example: https://res0ingresskong.resources.root.gc.local/onename


prefix /onename, target service the cluster IP port 443, strip path true and preserve host to false.

Under your current config, Kong will accept request to path /onename, strip it, and send / request to your .NET app.
This is default Kong configuration since normally API Gateway is used to mask upstream path.
If you want Kong's path and upstream's path to be the same, set strip_path to false
reference from the doc:
strip_path: When matching a Route via one of the paths, strip the matching prefix from the upstream request URL. Default: true.
Reference
